# markup validator on yahoo.com

Tags: asp.net, html

About to release a web site to production and wanted to run this in http://validator.w3.org/. I get a bunch of errors, something like "reference not terminated by REFC delimiter", "reference to external entity in attribute value", etc etc, and some legitimate "required attribute alt is not specified" etc.

I wanted to see how other sites are doing, so I tried yahoo.com and I see twice the amount of errors on it.

What errors need to be corrected or should I even bother? Perhaps this is not really very useful?

Comment: I'm voting to move this to the webmaster site because it's not really programming related, more a discussion on the merits of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators are often useful for making sure that your HTML is rendered correctly across browsers, but that particular validator is not always up to date with the latest standards.

It will be much better in the future (for you and other developers on your project) if you try to correct as many of those errors as you can.

Comment: what one is truly up to date if not from the W3C?

Comment: I wish I knew. It normally isn't a problem for most circumstances, but in the past I ran into Unicode problems (on their end, not mine), validator warnings about content-types, and straight up errors regarding validity of self-closing meta tags in the `<head>`. Sadly, the CSS validator is the one that's wrong most of the time. I wish they would just rewrite that from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Correct all of them if you care about valid HTML.

Comment: Just to know the consequences, what could go wrong if left as is. I mean the site is not broken in any browsers and Yahoo site has tons of them!

Comment: @coder net - Today it is not broken. And tomorrow? And in a browser you didn't test with?